# auto-fill form hidden fields from mySQL content showed in divs

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a checkout page with some info displayed after a while loop from mySQL in php and I now want those info auto-fill some hidden field in a form before an user insert his name and email and submit the form.
I'm new here so i hope in your help. Here's my code:

```html
<div class="modulo" style="background-image: url(images/<?php echo $url; ?>)"></div>
<h2 class="h2 style black"><?php echo $taglio;?> <?php echo $style; ?></h2>
<p class="paragraph" id="prezzo">prezzo:<br><?php echo $prezzo;?> €</p>
<div class="simple-text icon">mq:<br><?php echo $mq;?></div>
<div class="simple-text maiusc prova" id="piano">piano: <?php echo $piano;?></div>
<div class="simple-text maiusc prova">mood: <?php echo $mood;?></div>     
<div class="simple-text maiusc prova">finiture: <?php echo $finiture;?></div>
<div id="serv" class="simple-text maiusc prova">plus: 1, 2<br></div>

<form id="email-form-2" name="email-form-2" data-name="Email Form 2">
<input type="text" class="field-hidden w-input" maxlength="256" name="<?php echo $piano;?>" data-name="piano" placeholder="piano" id="piano">
<input type="text" class="field-hidden w-input" maxlength="256" name="<?php echo $mq;?>" data-name="mq" placeholder="mq" id="mq">
<input type="text" class="field-hidden w-input" maxlength="256" name="<?php echo $mood;?>" data-name="mood" placeholder="mood" id="mood">
<input type="text" class="field-hidden w-input" maxlength="256" name="<?php echo $finiture;?>" data-name="finiture" placeholder="finiture" id="finiture">
<input type="text" class="field-hidden w-input" maxlength="256" name="???" data-name="plus" placeholder="plus" id="plus">
<input type="text" class="field-hidden w-input" maxlength="256" name="<?php echo $prezzo_piano;?>" data-name="prezzo" placeholder="prezzo" id="price">
<label for="nome">nome:</label>
<input type="text" class="w-input" maxlength="256" name="nome" data-name="name" placeholder="inserisci il tuo nome" id="nome">
<label for="email">email:</label>
<input type="text" class="w-input" maxlength="256" name="email" data-name="Email" placeholder="inserisci la tua emal" id="email" required="">
<input type="submit" value="invia" data-wait="attendi" class="w-button">
```

thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't you be filling the value attribute with the variables, not name?

Comment: Use `type="hidden"` for hidden inputs, not `type="text"`.

Comment: Ho Davon, So if I pass this variable through value it will work? I

Comment: @StefanoZanetti yes. Use type=hidden and pass what you need into value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use:
`value="<?php echo $piano;?>"` instead of `name="<?php echo $piano;?>`

example:

`<input type="text" class="field-hidden w-input" maxlength="256" value="<?php echo $piano;?>" name="piano" placeholder="piano" id="piano">`